# if this annotation not written to bytecode, how is it able to be accessed at runtime?

Tags: java, annotations

> - `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`: Discard during
>     the compile. These annotations don't
>     make any sense after the compile   has
>     completed, so they aren't written to
>     the bytecode.
>     Example: `@Override`, `@SuppressWarnings`

If the following annotation named `MyAnno` not written to bytecode (.class file), how can I access it at runtime ? Example.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@interface MyAnno {
    int a = 4;
    int val();
}

public class Example {

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("MyAnno.a = " + MyAnno.a);
        MyAnno myAnno = new MyAnno() {
            public int val() {
                return 7;
            }
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        System.out.println("myAnno.val = " + myAnno.val());

        Override ov = new Override() {
            public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```

This above code is running without any error.

Comment: If you would need the annotation at runtime what is wrong with `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`? What you are trying to achive in the sdample code is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RetentionPolicy is about the class files of classes, where you added the annotation to, not the class file of the annotation itself, e.g.

```
@MyAnno
public class TestClass {}
```

`RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` means, that if you add the annotation to the class, and then try to get all annotations of that class by using `TestClass.class.getAnnotations()`, it will not be part of the result.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the purpose of `RetentionPolicy`: it is there to specify what happens to annotations done with your type, not to the type itself.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Retention.html) states the following:

> A Retention meta-annotation has effect only if the meta-annotated type is used directly for annotation. It has no effect if the meta-annotated type is used as a member type in another annotation type.

Your program uses meta-annotated type `MyAnno` directly, rather than using it for annotation. Hence, retention policy annotation has no effect.